# PYTHON : How to fix for loop stop?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to extract over 24 product names from multiple pages but my for loop only return 1 product name. I need the script to go to a individual product page and extract product name and the go back to 
page url list and repeat the same steps.

The script below on return the first product name and then stop.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

HROMEDRIVER_PATH = '/Users/reezalaq/PycharmProjects/wholesale/driver/chromedriver'
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=chrome_options)
chrome_options.accept_untrusted_certs = True
chrome_options.assume_untrusted_cert_issuer = True
chrome_options.headless = False

home = "https://www.blibli.com/c/4/beli--mukena/MU-1000008/54912?page=1&start=0&category=MU-1000008&sort=7&intent=false"
driver.get(home)
for number in range(1, 24):
    elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="catalogProductListContentDiv"]/div[3]/div[' + str(number) + ']/div/div/a')
    for link in elem:
        producturl = link.get_attribute("href")
        time.sleep(24)
        driver.get(producturl)
        getproductname = driver.find_element_by_class_name("product__name-text")
        print(getproductname.text)
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this by opening a new tab, then switching to the new tab.

First, wait until all your elements are visible.

Instead of `time.sleep (24)` you can use `WebDriverWait`.

This is the element you mean:

```
//div[@class="product__item"]/a
```

You can try the below code:

```
driver.get('https://www.blibli.com/c/4/beli--mukena/MU-1000008/54912?page=1&start=0&category=MU-1000008&sort=7&intent=false')

elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="product__item"]/a')))
for element in elements:
    url = element.get_attribute('href')
    #open new tab with specific url
    driver.execute_script("window.open('" +url +"');")
    #switch to new tab
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    getproductname = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'product__name-text')))
    print(getproductname.text)
    #close current tab
    driver.close()
    #back to first tab
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
driver.quit()
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```